# Pre-compile specific directories in ASP.NET website project

Tags: asp.net, deployment, compilation, precompiled, vs-web-site-project

I have an ASP.NET website project which has a mixture of updateable pages and pages that do not change.

Is it possible for me to pre-compile certain directories that contain pages/controls that will not be updated?

If so, how could I designate these directories as such?

**Edit 2009.12.17**

My project is structured like this:

> **/cms_pages**   ==> Updateable .aspx pages marked CompilationMode="never" and no code file.
>
> **/app_pages**   ==> .aspx pages with .aspx.cs code file.
>
> **/controls**   ==> .ascx controls with .ascx.cs code file.

I would like to "pre-compile" the **app_pages** and **controls** folders.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not without a lot of headaches.  How are you precompiling the pages now?  They must be in a WAP for this to work... so anything you DON'T want precompiled just leave out of the project.

[Edit]

It's possible to manually call the asp.net compiler.  But I don't recommend this.  What you really need to do is split up your solution files into different projects... put the files you want pre-compiled into a Web Application Project or just a regular class library.  Then in your Web Site add a project reference to this WAP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to compile your ASPX pages with their codefiles or just compile some .cs files in your App_Code folder?

If you're just trying to version control some static functions or global objects you can compile a DLL to keep in your App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just pre-compile all of the controls (and probably anything else) into an assembly then you can access them through myAssembly.myControl

```
 Dim assembly As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(Server.MapPath(Virtual path to assembly))
```

Dim myControlType As Type = assembly.GetType
     Dim myControl As UserControl = LoadControl(myControlType, Nothing)
     myPanel.Controls.Add(myControl )

Or

```
Dim myControl As Control = LoadControl(virtual path to control)
myPanel.Controls.Add(myControl )
```

Hope this helps..